# How to scan text file for word and word count?

Tags: c, file, text, word-count

How can I scan for a text file for a word and increment the count every time it gets scanned?

My program main takes two keywords and a number of files as command line arguments. Each file passed as an argument on the command line will contain a list of messages of at most 160 characters.
So for example:

```
$ ./main Hello Bye data1.txt data2.txt
```

will output

```
3 messages containing Hello and 1 messages containing Bye
2 messages containing Hello and 2 messages containing Bye
```

In my do_file method in main.c, stats_add_data() doesn't work when called and I don't know why. I've checked the pointers and they seem to be correct.

```
void do_file(char *filename, char *key1, char *key2) {

    stats *newstats;
    newstats = stats_create(key1, key2);

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    char *keyword1 = newstats->key1;
    char *keyword2 = newstats->key2;

    int line_num = 1;
    int find_result1 = 0;
    int find_result2 = 0;
    char temp[160];

    const char delimter[1] = " ";
    char onewordtoken[160];

    // Get a line, up to 160 chars from file
    while(fgets(temp, 160, f) != NULL) {
        if((strstr(temp, key1)) != NULL) {
            printf("A match found on line: %d\n", line_num);
            printf("\n%s\n", temp);
            find_result1++;

            stats_add_data(newstats, temp);

            stats_print(newstats);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        if((strstr(temp, key2)) != NULL) {
            printf("A match found on line: %d\n", line_num);
            printf("\n%s\n", temp);
            find_result2++;

            stats_add_data(newstats, temp);

            stats_print(newstats);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        line_num++;
    }

    if((find_result1 == 0) && (find_result2 == 0)) {
        printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
    }
}
```

CODE FOR REFERENCE:

stats.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stats.h"

// The stats_create function should allocate and return a new stats structure, storing key1 and key2 in the structâs string fields and setting the two integers to 0.
stats *stats_create(char *key1, char *key2) {
    stats *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    new->key1 = key1;
    new->key2 = key2;
    new->int1 = 0;
    new->int2 = 0;
    return new;
}

// The stats_add_data function should update the structure pointed to by s against the value val. That is, if val contains the first keyword, the integer containing the count of the number of messages containing that keyword should be updated. Similarly for the second keyword.
void stats_add_data(struct stats *s, char *val) {
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    char* key1 = s->key1;
    char* key2 = s->key2;

    if (strcmp(s->key1, val) == 0) {
        count1++;
    }
    if (strcmp(s->key2, val) == 0) {
        count2++;
    }

    count1 = s->int1;
    count2 = s->int2;
}

// The stats_print function should print on one line the number of messages containing the first keyword, and the number of keywords containing the second keyword. E.g. 2 messages containing Homeland and 2 messages containing Elementary.

void stats_print(struct stats *s) {
    int count1 = s->int1;
    int count2 = s->int2;
    char* key1 = s->key1;
    char* key2 = s->key2;

    printf("%d", count1);
    printf(" messages containing ");
    printf("%s", key1);
    printf(" and ");
    printf("%d", count2);
    printf(" messages containing ");
    printf("%s", key2);
}

// The stats_free function should free the given stats structure and any memory that might have been allocated for it.
void stats_free(struct stats *s) {
    if(s) {
        free(s);
    }
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stats.h"

// A function void do_file(char *filename, char *key1, char*key2) that takes a file name and two keywords as its arguments. It should create a statistics struct that will be used to accumulate the statistics about the data in the file.

//Open the given filename, and iterate over each line of the file, reading in the data value and updating the statistics struct. Once the file has been read, close it and display the results.
void do_file(char *filename, char *key1, char *key2) {

    stats *newstats;
    newstats = stats_create(key1, key2);

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    char *keyword1 = newstats->key1;
    char *keyword2 = newstats->key2;
    //char keyword1 = *key1;
    //char keyword2 = *key2;

    int line_num = 1;
    int find_result1 = 0;
    int find_result2 = 0;
    char temp[160];

    if((f = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("File does not exist!\n");
    }

    const char delimter[1] = " ";
    char onewordtoken[160];

    // Get a line, up to 160 chars from file
    while(fgets(temp, 160, f) != NULL) {
        if((strstr(temp, key1)) != NULL) {
            printf("A match found on line: %d\n", line_num);
            printf("\n%s\n", temp);
            find_result1++;

            stats_add_data(newstats, temp);

            stats_print(newstats);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        if((strstr(temp, key2)) != NULL) {
            printf("A match found on line: %d\n", line_num);
            printf("\n%s\n", temp);
            find_result2++;

            stats_add_data(newstats, temp);

            stats_print(newstats);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        line_num++;
    }

    stats_free(newstats);

    if((find_result1 == 0) && (find_result2 == 0)) {
        printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
    }

    // Close the file if still open
    if(f) {
        fclose(f);
    }
}

// A main function that iterates over each file argument, except the first, and runs do_file on it. After the 0th argument, the first two command line arguments will be the keywords to process. The remaining arguments will be the file arguments.

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if(argc > 2) {
        //printf("The argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
        //stats_add_data();
        do_file("data.txt", argv[1], argv[2]);
        printf("\n\n");
        //stats_free(s);
    } else {
        printf("Too few arguments supplied.\n");
        //stats_free(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `count1 = s->int1;` This appears at the end of your add data function. You probably want that with the order of arguments reversed.

Comment: Problems/weaknesses: 1) `if (strcmp(s->key1, val)` only works if `key1` and `val` are the same, not if `key1` is contained within `val`.  2) Code is set up to count lines, not occurrences.  Consider keyword may occur mutilate times in a line.  3) doe not handle `key="aba"` occurring 2x in `line = "ababa"`  4) assumes key does not occur across line boundaries `key = "a\nb"`. 5) "line, up to 160 chars from file" needs a buffer at least 1 wider.

Comment: still not executable.  The contents of `stats.h` are not posted.

Comment: when compiling, enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use `-Wconversion -std-gnu99` )

Comment: why are you using `stats` in some places in the posted code and `struct stats` in others,  certainly you do not have a `typedef` statement of the kind: `typedef struct stats stats;`

Comment: given this line in the question: `$ ./main Hello Bye data1.txt data2.txt`, then this line in the code: `do_file("data.txt", argv[1], argv[2]);` is not correct.  rather it should be: `for( int i=2; i<argc; i++ ) { do_file( argv[i], argv[1], argv[2] ); }`

Answer (score 0):

When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

The following code cleanly compiles and eliminates to of the sub functions (they become one liners in the rest of the code.)

The function: `free()` properly handles a NULL pointer, so no need to test the pointer for NULL before calling `free()`

The posted code is missing the contents of `stats.h` so I inserted prototypes and a `struct stats` definition and a `typedef` statement

(very bad idea to make the struct tagname and a typedef name the same)

the check for minimal number of command line arguments should output a `usage` message to stderr, not to stdout and should indicate the correct command line parameters format.

modified very long comments to fit on the page including minor content changes.

Here is the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include "stats.h"
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN (160)

struct stats
{
    char *key1;
    char *key2;
    int int1;
    int int2;
};

typedef struct stats stats;


// prototypes
stats *stats_create(char *key1, char *key2);
#if 0
    void stats_add_data(struct stats *s, char *val);
#endif
void stats_print(struct stats *s);
#if 0
    void stats_free(struct stats *s);
#endif
void do_file(char *filename, char *key1, char *key2);


// the following comment is not correct:

/*
 * A main function that iterates over each file argument, 
 * except the first, and runs do_file on it. 
 * After the 0th argument, 
 * the first two command line arguments will be the 
 * keywords to process. 
 *The remaining arguments will be the file arguments.
 */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //if(argc > 2)
    if( argc > 3 )
    {
        //printf("The argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
        //stats_add_data();
        for( int i=3; i<argc; i++ )
        {
            do_file( argv[i], argv[1], argv[2] );
        }
        //do_file("data.txt", argv[1], argv[2]);
        printf("\n\n");
        //stats_free(s);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Too few arguments supplied.\n");
        //stats_free(s);
    }
} // end function: main



/*
 * The stats_create function should allocate 
 * and return a new stats structure, 
 * storing key1 and key2 in the struct 
 * as pointers to string fields and setting the two integers to 0.
 */

stats *stats_create(char *key1, char *key2)
{
    stats *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    new->key1 = key1;
    new->key2 = key2;
    new->int1 = 0;
    new->int2 = 0;
    return new;
} // end function: stats_create


#if 0
    // The stats_add_data function should update the structure pointed to by s against the value val. That is, if val contains the first keyword, the integer containing the count of the number of messages containing that keyword should be updated. Similarly for the second keyword.
    void stats_add_data(struct stats *s, char *val)
    {
        //int count1 = 0;
        //int count2 = 0;
        // char* key1 = s->key1;
        // char* key2 = s->key2;

        if (strcmp(s->key1, val) == 0)
        {
            //count1++;
            s->int1++;
        }

        if (strcmp(s->key2, val) == 0)
        {
            //count2++;
            s->int2++;
        }

        //count1 = s->int1;
        //count2 = s->int2;
    } // end function: stats_add_data
#endif

/*
 * The stats_print function should print on one line
 * the number of messages containing the first keyword, 
 * and the number of messages containing the second keyword. 
 * E.g. 2 messages containing Homeland and 2 messages containing Elementary.
 */

void stats_print(struct stats *s)
{
    //int count1 = s->int1;
    //int count2 = s->int2;
    //char* key1 = s->key1;
    //char* key2 = s->key2;

    //printf("%d", count1);
    //printf(" messages containing ");
    //printf("%s", key1);
    //printf(" and ");
    //printf("%d", count2);
    //printf(" messages containing ");
    //printf("%s", key2);
    printf( "%d messages containing <%s> and %d messages containing <%s>\n",
            s->int1, s->key1, s->int2, s->key2 );
} // end function: stats_print


#if 0
    // The stats_free function should free the given stats structure and any memory that might have been allocated for it.
    void stats_free(struct stats *s)
    {
        if(s) {
            free(s);
        }
    } // end function: stats_free
#endif

/*
 * A function void do_file(char *filename, char *key1, char*key2)
 * that takes a file name and two keywords as its arguments. 
 * It should create a statistics struct 
 * that will be used to accumulate the statistics
 * about the data in the individual file.
 */

/*
 * Open the given filename, 
 * iterate over each line of the file, 
 * searching for the two key words in the line
 * updating the statistics struct for each line read. 
 * after the whole file has been read, 
 * close it and display the results.
 */

void do_file(char *filename, char *key1, char *key2)
{

    stats *newstats = NULL;
    newstats = stats_create(key1, key2);

    // FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    // char *keyword1 = newstats->key1;
    // char *keyword2 = newstats->key2;
    // char keyword1 = *key1;
    // char keyword2 = *key2;

    int line_num = 1;
    // int find_result1 = 0;
    // int find_result2 = 0;
    char temp[ MAX_LINE_LEN+1]; //+1 to allow for NUL terminator byte

    FILE *f = NULL;
    if((f = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "fopen for %s failed due to: %s\n", filename, strerror( errno ) );
        // exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        return;
        //printf("File does not exist!\n");
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    // const char delimter[1] = " ";
    // char onewordtoken[160];

    // Get a line, up to 160 chars from file
    while(fgets(temp, sizeof temp, f) != NULL)
    {
        if((strstr(temp, key1)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("A match found on line: %d\n", line_num);
            printf("\n%s\n", temp);
            //find_result1++;

            //stats_add_data(newstats, temp);
            newstats->int1++;

            stats_print(newstats);
            printf("\n\n");
        }

        if((strstr(temp, key2)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("A match found on line: %d\n", line_num);
            printf("\n%s\n", temp);
            //find_result2++;

            //stats_add_data(newstats, temp);
            newstats->int2++;

            //stats_print(newstats);
            //printf("\n\n");
        }

        line_num++;
    } // end while

    stats_print( newstats );
    printf("\n\n");

    // stats_free(newstats);

    //if((find_result1 == 0) && (find_result2 == 0)) {
    if( 0 == newstats->int1 && 0 == newstats->int2 )
    {
        printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
    }

    free( newstats );

    // Close the file if still open
    //if(f) {
    //    fclose(f);
    //}
    // would not get here if file did not open
    fclose( f );
} // end function: do_file
```

Comment: My posted answer needs updates for the 'usage' statement when not enough command line arguments supplied.  Needs update to check for failure of the call to `malloc()`. Needs modification to check for multiple instances of the same keyword on a single input line.  The supplied 160 line length, does that include the trailing newline?